# Why is my Sinatra app showing a blank screen?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

My Sinatra app was working on my local server a few days ago, but now it simply isn't running, and all I get is a blank screen. Even when I deploy to Heroku, nothing works.

Here's a GitHub repository where you can check out my code: https://github.com/aayalur/Sinfoursq

I think the problem is with my `config.ru` file.

```
# Gemfile
#require "rubygems"
#require "bundler/setup"
#require "sinatra"

require "./main"

set :run, false
set :raise_errors, true

run Sinatra::Application
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is showing some error in the console?

Comment: Please don't refer us to an outside link to see your code. If that link dies or you alter your code then your question becomes invalid and has no value for anyone else who has the same issue in the future.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the config.ru, but I won't change it in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You app doesn't display anything because you haven't closed a script tag. You would have noticed that if you inspected the DOM.

By the way, you start your app twice: once in *main.rb*, and then in *config.ru*.
You can notice that when <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>'ing the app: it starts again and you gotta shut it down a second time.

Since your app needs to be run on Rack, get rid of the `Sinatra.run! if __FILE__ == $0` and start it with `rackup`, as explained in [Sinatra's documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Serving%20a%20Modular%20Application).

This will fix the problems related to running the app.

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your config.ru leave this way:

```
require "rubygems"
require "bundler"

Bundler.require

require "./app"
run Sinatra::Application
```

Comment: ok but the console is showing rendering of js and css files? And what is the command you are using the server to go up? foreman start?

Comment: No the console is blank. I am using `ruby main.rb` or `rackup`

Comment: Hi so I think the problem is caching css and js files I did pull one of your project and was not showing anything at all, and I configured the static_assets sinatra is now ok. Then try to configure assets and tell if it worked